# User space programs writing to anywhere

Tags: linux, unix, linux-kernel, kernel

Regarding the Unix kernel for example. There are some things i don't quite get in terms of kernel space and user space.

We will have user space application code and kernel code. The Kernel code has unrestricted access to the underlying hardware and its code and memory are completely separate to user space code.

When a user space application is executing, is the kernel code also executing in parallel, such as kernel threads always checking things?

I've been reading that the kernel provides memory protection of user space programs trying to access restricted parts of memory. Is this memory protection happening dynamically, or will it be during compilation, an error if user space code tries to write to a restricted part of memory?

In general, what is to stop a user space program from writing to anywhere it wants in memory if the kernel code is not executing at the same time? I would guess and say that it is because of the MMU and virtual memory, but is there more to it? Thanks

Comment: User space programs do not directly access system resources, they do it by means of methods provided by system libraries. That is where the checks occur.

Comment: Ok, but what happens if i compile a user space program to access a system resource, like directly writing to  a register for GPIO for example, When and where is the protection implemented?

Comment: User processes don't have access to all instructions of the processor set, nor they have access to real memory only to virtual memory. Everything that is considered as "dangerous" is forbidden to user processes and protection is usually enforced by hardware support. More generally a user process has no access to the real machine only to some virtual machine (defined by the system).

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès but my application code accessing restricted memory will compile ok? On an ARM7 processor for example, in user mode, I can write to any GPIO directly etc. My understanding is that the memory protection is implemented by the kernel, but how?

Comment: @Engineer999 Probably because the GPIO is mapped into your user space.

Comment: When running embedded linux however, the GPIOs will not be mapped to user space. The GPIOs must be accessed via the kernel.

Comment: *"When running embedded linux ..."* -- Embedded Linux system are notorious for having poor security.  Buildroot, for example, has a default configuration with a single user, **root**, with *no* password.  So you can easily login as a superuser, and have access to **/dev/mem** without any restrictions. @Engineer999 --You're contradicting yourself with *"in user mode, I can write to any GPIO directly etc"*, and then *"The GPIOs must be accessed via the kernel."*  *"My understanding is that the memory protection is implemented by the kernel"* -- Your *"understanding"* is incorrect.

Comment: Memory protection is implemented by the kernel, how exactly tho, at runtime or how? This part I don't fully understand. A userspace program will have its time with the CPU, so then if it tries to write to restricted memory, what will happen?

Comment: @Engineer999  *"Memory protection is implemented by the kernel"* -- Repeating a (false) statement isn't going to make it true.  *"This part I don't fully understand."* -- The salient part of a false statement is that it's false.  How it works cannot be explained when it's false.  *"... what will happen?"* -- I've already written an answer for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When a user space application is executing, is the kernel code also executing in parallel, such as kernel threads always checking things?

No.

> Is this memory protection happening dynamically, or will it be during compilation, an error if user space code tries to write to a restricted part of memory?

The memory restrictions are enforced dynamically by memory management hardware in conjunction with the [CPU mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_modes).
The kernel configures these restrictions, i.e. MMU initialization, during boot.

A compiler typically does not perform any address enforcement.  It's easy to generate code that access an array beyond its bounds.  Likewise it's easy to generate pointers that reference "restricted" memory.  Note that the compilation stage typically does not assume the runtime environment (e.g. does kernel space occupy 1 GB or 2GB of the 32-bit virtual address space?), so compiled programs are more portable.

> In general, what is to stop a user space program from writing to anywhere it wants in memory if the kernel code is not executing at the same time?

A userspace program simply executes with restricted CPU privileges that inhibit certain operations.
Additionally it executes in its own restricted virtual memory space, apart from other processes.
BTW a CPU can (essentially) only execute one instruction at a time, so there is no *"kernel code ... executing at the same time"*, and the premise is irrelevant.

> is there more to it?

The CPU must have [privilege mode(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_modes); not all CPUs have this capability. The Intel CPUs of early PCs, e.g. 8088 and 80286, did not.

*"When a user space application is executing"*, the CPU is in user mode, the mode with the least privileges/capabilities. Kernel code is executed in a supervisor/privileged (aka kernel) mode.

> When and where is the protection implemented?

As each instruction is executed, the CPU validates that instruction according to the current CPU mode.  An attempt to execute a privileged instruction in a restricted mode triggers a CPU exception.
If the instruction also involves a memory reference, then the MMU validates that virtual memory address (i.e. user versus kernel space) based on the current CPU mode (i.e. user versus kernel mode).
For a valid memory reference, the MMU would then confirm that physical memory is mapped for that virtual address, and that the memory page is resident.

---

**ADDENDUM**

You seem to be conflating the restrictions on accessing virtual memory and physical memory.
Your userspace program only can access lower virtual memory.  The boundary is defined by the kernel.  Access to kernel space is denied by hardware, specifically the MMU in conjunction with the CPU mode.

Your (userspace) program only can access the memory space that the OS provides for it.  Programming languages have no built-in constructs to an alternate (e.g. physical instead of virtual) address space.  Protected-mode Windows (i.e. Windows NT and later, not Windows 3.x) does not offer programs access to physical memory.  POSIX operating systems offer the pseudo-device **/dev/mem** for memory mapping any physical address to user (virtual) address space.

Since ARM processors have no I/O instructions or address space, all I/O is therefore memory mapped.  Consequently **/dev/mem** is the device to access peripherals connected to an ARM processor that runs Linux.
Access to the pseudo-device **/dev/mem** is controlled by the kernel (just like every other file) using filesystem permissions.

Comment: Very helpful answer. Just one question - what are some operations that are inhibited by the CPU mode? (I've never heard of CPU modes)

Comment: @SridharSarnobat -- An answer would be CPU specific.  Did you read the linked articles?

Comment: Not yet, I'll do that to answer my question